# when transfer app to another developer account - Unable to process request

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, transfer

I create one app and I sell it to another dev.

### When I try to transfer my the app to the other developer account, by clicking in the 'transfer app' button in itunesconnect, I receive the following error message.

Unable to Process Request

### Your request could not be processed. For additional help, send an email to itunesconnect@apple.com.

All my apps receive the same error if I try to tranfers them.

I send an email now to itunesconnect, but I want to know if more people have the same problem.

I found all the app, its status is Ready for Sale. As long as Iclick Transfer app,

Will appear :
Unable to Process Request

Your request could not be processed. For additional help, send anemail to itunesconnect@apple.com.

I tried operating system windows8.1, ubuntu13.1, Mac OSX10.9.1, isthe same problem.

I tried the browser : IE11.0, GoogleChrome_version_33.0,FirefoxESR,
Opera12.15, Safari5.1.7, all of the same problems are tried.

Comment: Well how about sending an e-mail to itunesconnect@apple.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an iTunes Connect site issue.

Comment: I have same problem, sent a mail to itunesconnect@apple.com. Let's see if they are going to resolve this issue as a high priority.

Comment: My problem is not solved yet,today.And about week passed.

Comment: Just found out you can transfer app, the problem is resolved, hee hee.